# Fabric internals of Block data

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Ledger has a World state and Transaction log.

**Interested to know,**

```
1) Where exactly transaction log file is stored

2) How can I view the complete content of Block (any example, how it looks instead of diagrams). Is the block data saved in JSON format ??

3) Please share the documentation on how the data hash and previous block hash are created using the specific algorithm


4) What is the exact type of data structure is used to create the transaction log
```

This link will provide a basic overview:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/ledger/ledger.html#blockchain

Any documentation to understand the internal.

Answer (score 3):

1. All the `world state` and `transaction log` stored in the `peer` container.
   `LevelDB or CouchDB` stores the world state while `transaction log` stored as `ledger`.

   > I don't know where exactly it saves the ledger.
2. A Block saves in a protobuf format. [Block Data Definition - fabric-node-sdk](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/global.html#Block)
   To get the [block data](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/Channel.html#queryBlock__anchor).

```
An object of a fully decoded protobuf message "Block".

A Block may contain the configuration of the channel or transactions on the channel.

A Block object will have the following object structure.
header
    number -- {int}
    previous_hash -- {byte[]}
    data_hash -- {byte[]}
data
    data -- {array}
        signature -- {byte[]}
        payload
            header -- {Header}
            data -- {ConfigEnvelope | Transaction}
metadata
    metadata -- {array} #each array item has it's own layout
        [0] #SIGNATURES
            signatures -- {MetadataSignature[]}
        [1] #LAST_CONFIG
            value
                index -- {number}
                signatures -- {MetadataSignature[]}
        [2] #TRANSACTIONS_FILTER
                {int[]} #see TxValidationCode in proto/peer/transaction.proto
```

3. The `SHA256` algorithm is used to encrypt the block. A block is encrypted using: `block number, current block hash, previous block hash, block data and block metadata`.

   ### [Ledger](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/ledger/ledger.html#blocks) [more](https://openblockchain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-spec/)
4. Same as point 2.